# Need some help identifying my new project

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I need some help identifying my new project. I  would like to get new decals for it.

Only 'CICL' left on headbadge, can't figure out what's left on the down tube.

Numbers stamp on bottom bracket 52.

Campagnolo shifters, derailleurs, stamped Campy rear dropouts, front forks. Campy hubs with Mavic tubular rims. Dura-ace headset, Madolo Pro brakes, 3ttt (Italy) handlebar and stem.

What's your best guess? Ane suggestion is it is a Vanni Losa frame.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Guessing it says "cervinia" or "cerdinia" but google's not showing anything useful

Comment: You can attach bigger images - no need to cram them all into one composite image.  If the editor says no, just upload the images to imgur and provide link to the album.

Comment: Could it be Cervello @criggie

Comment: @DanK I can certainly see "cerv" but after that it goes astray.  The Cervelo logo has never really changed, and never used a font face like this.

Comment: I'd suggest that since many Losa frames seem to have italian names, it probably says 'Cervinia' which is a region of italy.  The style of the lettering does match this Losa frame:
https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/~jAAAOSwq4Vb6FfW/s-l1600.jpg

Comment: @AndyP that's an awesome find - it has the same yellow V shaped chevrons on the crown and head tube and lugs.

Comment: Is there something written/stamped on the top of the seat stays? Suggestions for how to maximize the chances of identifying a bike. https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: First would like thank everyone for all the input of discovery.nothing stamped or written on seat stays. In side the front fork stars on arms.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a bad answer and is only here to share progress so far, and hopefully inspire an answer from someone else.

First up  "cicle" is Catalan for "cycle"  so that definitely points at a European basis.  We don't know if that sticker is from the manufacturer or a retailer that sold the bike, but the easternmost part of Spain is where Catalan is spoken.

---

By combining the three images of the logo, I get this composite:

[image: Own work]

Which doesn't look like anything. Googling shows no ligatures that are a combination of C and Z, but does hint that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87 may fit.

The V is too wide and the H is too narrow and character 6 isn't anything recognisable - Russian has a backward R (Яя) but its capitalised not lowercase.

Go back to Catalan though, and there are "dz" and   "dʒ" as consonants , from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_language#Phonology

Catalan-based bicycle companies include Orbea, and Rasaba Cycles.

---

Your idea of Losa is certainly possible.  Here's an image of the fork crown, inside fork leg, and head tube of a known Losa frame.  From http://go-mamil.bike/losa-background

[image]

Similar but different, and the fork doesn't have the "chevrons" on the inside, which are V for Vanni according to that link above.

Vanni Losa was an artisan framebuilder who built many frames for other brands - so anything's possible.

---

A frame number of 52 on the BB definitely implies a low-throughput framebuilder - German Tank theory suggests a total output of ~104 bikes.

Comment: I have come up with Cervinia, unfortunately nothing bike related in the short time but it does tie in to Italy and France. Maybe something else to go on at a later date. @Andy P sorry just realised you posted above, my phone doesn't always update

Comment: I'm seeing something closer to "cerdinia".

Comment: thank you for the help still working on Id very helpful .